# Error listening on port: 127.0.0.1:2222, "listen tcp 127.0.0.1:2222: bind: address already in use"

Tags: nats.io

I am trying to start a NATS server.

Downloaded **nats-server-v2.9.2-linux-amd64** and started the executable by terminal command.

```
 cd  /home/nats/ 
 ./server --a 127.0.0.1 --port 2222
```

The default 0.0.0.0 and port 4222 gave the same error. And this is the error:

```
[3265] 2022/10/04 11:28:20.779634 [INF] Starting nats-server
[3265] 2022/10/04 11:28:20.779813 [INF]   Version:  2.9.2
[3265] 2022/10/04 11:28:20.779846 [INF]   Git:      [6d81dde]
[3265] 2022/10/04 11:28:20.779883 [INF]   Name:     NDQU3V6PO7F63NIRX7AC65QZKB3DM73OIJADYBIO2JJMQOEE5HZSYE4Q
[3265] 2022/10/04 11:28:20.779911 [INF]   ID:       NDQU3V6PO7F63NIRX7AC65QZKB3DM73OIJADYBIO2JJMQOEE5HZSYE4Q
[3265] 2022/10/04 11:28:20.780183 [FTL] Error listening on port: 127.0.0.1:2222, "listen tcp 127.0.0.1:2222: bind: address already in use"
```

No docker involved. Just Debian 10 at root /home/nats/.
What am I doing wrong?